# tkinter window.iconbitmap functions crashes application(compiled by pyinstaller)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, icons, pyinstaller

I am creating soft with Tkinter. I am trying to set an icon using root.iconbitmap('Globe.ico'). it works fine when I launch code. But after I compile it with pyinstaller it crashes. when i remove root.iconbitmap('Globe.ico') function and compile it works fine. bellow is error and the code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word.py", line 294, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1871, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "Global.ico" not defined
[5128] Failed to execute script word

from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

root.title("some title")
#line bellow crashes app
root.iconbitmap('Global.ico') 

progress=Progressbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=500,mode='indeterminate')
progress.grid(row=3,column=1)


l2 = Label(root, text="File Name").grid(row=0,column =0)

e1_value =StringVar()
e1=Entry(root,textvariable=e1_value,width=80)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

b1 = Button(root, text = "Select Folder",command = directory )
b1.grid(row=1,column =0)

b2 = Button(root, text = "Execute",command = run_transformations )
b2.grid(row=4,column=1)

t1 = Text(root,height=1,width=60)
t1.grid(row=1,column =1 )
t1.configure(state='disabled')

v = IntVar()
r1 = Radiobutton(root,text='Rows as Columns',variable=v , value = 1).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan =2,ipadx = 100)
r2 = Radiobutton(root,text='Columns as Columns',variable=v , value = 2).grid(row=2,column=1 ,columnspan =3,ipadx = 0)

v.set(1)
buttons = [ b1,b2]
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `pyinstaller` without `-w`, run the `.exe` form a `console` window, [edit] your question and show the `Traceback` you are getting.

Comment: Does it crash with an error? What's the error?

Comment: I edited the question. have a look, please.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Full path would solve this issue.
ex) root.iconbitmap('d:\test\Global.ico')